# Using bash, I want to print a number followed by sizes of 2 paths on one line. i.e. output of 3 commands on one line

Tags: linux, bash

Using bash, I want to print a number followed by sizes of 2 paths on one line. i.e. output of 3 commands on one line.

All the 3 items should be separated by ":"

```
echo -n "10001:"; du -sch /abc/def/* | grep 'total' | awk '{ print $1 }'; du -sch /ghi/jkl/* | grep 'total' | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

I am getting the output as -

```
10001:61M

:101M
```

But I want the output as -

```
10001:61M:101M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. The two key elements added being the 
 tr - d '\n'
which effectively strips new line characters from the end of the output. As well as adding in the echo ":" to get the extra colon for formatting in there.

Hope this helps! Here's a link to the docs for tr command. 
https://ss64.com/bash/tr.html

```
echo -n "10001:"; du -sch /abc/def/* | grep 'total' | awk '{ print $1 }' | tr -d '\n'; echo ":" | tr -d '\n'; du -sch /ghi/jkl/* | grep 'total' | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your values to variables, and then use `printf`:

```
printf '%s:%s:%s\n' "$first" "$second" "$third"
```